# Does current flow across 0 resistance and 0 potential difference?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current

For the following circuit, will current flow from ***3'***  to ***3***. I know that both are at 0V. However, the resistance between ***3'***  to ***3*** is 0 ohms. So, ohms law would give the current as 0/0 which is indeterminate. So what would the current be?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: It will be whatever KCL dictates it should be.

Comment: What comes in, goes out. R=U/I - let's say I = GA, U=0, so R=0, no more indeterminate.

Comment: How many times this question has been answered in ESE..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short circuit = zero voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/360161/short-circuit-zero-voltage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's indeterminate.

Think about it this way: if you have zero ohms, it will never have a non-zero voltage drop across it. The voltage drop is always zero regardless of whether there is zero amps, 1 amp, 10 amps, a million amps, or infinite amps flowing through it. Which means you can't use the voltage drop across it to try and determine the current flowing through it. It's a mathematical singularity if you look at just that one part of the circuit.

But nature has "all the mathematics", both known and unknown by humans, at its disposal and "uses" this to work around these things. Technically though, in this case nature doesn't "use" math so much as it just never allows zero ohm conductors. It prevents ideals from every becoming reality that way and introducing contradictions and conundrums. That's the problem with ideal things. They don't make sense in all cases (edge cases in particular).

In this case, the physical meaning is the part of the circuit you are focusing on does not determine the current flowing through it. It is other parts of the circuit that determine the current flow.

Comment: As I x 0 = 0. So I can be anything

Comment: @dilinex Yes. A mathematical singularities tend to mean you approached the problem the wrong way or use an inappropriate set of mathematical tools. The more math we figure out, the more humans can calculate "how" "nature" goes about its own math to get around these limitations. We're kinda stuck at quantum gravity though.

Comment: Superconductors say hi. It appears nature is quite happy with zero ohm conductors.

Comment: @user110971 It's pushing the limit, but there are still catches. It's not true mathematical zero. For example, energy is still lost through electromagnetic emissions and magnetic field coupling, not to mention that you can't force an infinite amount of current through a finite volume of super conductor without something resembling resistance appearing.

Comment: @DKNguyen It is actually mathematically zero. Superconductors can sustain injected currents pretty much indefinitely. Here is just one example: https://www.astro.oma.be/en/world-record-in-the-underground-laboratory-of-membach/

Answer (score 0):

Your 'circuit' is exactly equivalent to this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwBy5l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Voltage exists across nodes, and current flows between them. But your 'circuit' only has a single node, so there is nowhere for a voltage to be developed across or a current to come from. Is it even a circuit?

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes when discussing r.f. circuits, an object will be described as a “perfect electrical conductor”. This “zero ohm“ thing has well defined, finite currents that flow through it, even though there are no voltage drops across it. So the answer to your question in this case is yes, current does flow across something with zero ohms and zero volts across it. Using this idea one can determine, for example, how much current will flow in a wire antenna when it is exposed to an electromagnetic plane wave.